# User authentication using php and mySql

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Am facing challenges in the following code; please help:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if (!$con){
       die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $db_exist = mysql_select_db("seta", $con);

    $myUName = $_POST["username"];
    $myPwd = $_POST["pwd"];
    $loFmUname = strtolower($myUName);

    if($db_exist){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE $loFmUname = 'strtolower($db_field['UserName'])' AND $myPwd = '$db_field['UserPwd']'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        if($result){
            $_session['loged'] = '$loFmUname';
            header('location:index.html');
            die();
        }

        else{
            echo"Invalid username and/or password please";
            echo "<a href='login.php'>try again</a>";
        }

    }

    else{
        echo "Sorry Database Not Found";
    }


 mysql_close($con);
 ?>
```

> The error is coming on line 15.

Note that `strtolower()` is being used to ignore case-sensitive username.

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE $loFmUname = 'strtolower($db_field['UserName'])' AND $myPwd = '$db_field['UserPwd']'";
```

By this one

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE $loFmUname = '".strtolower($db_field['UserName'])."' AND $myPwd = '".$db_field['UserPwd']."'";
```

This may help you.

Thanks

Comment: I strongly suggest calling `mysql_real_escape_string` before passing the data to the database, just for security reasons.

Comment: OR Just use LOWER() - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_lower

Comment: thanx jst did as u said, it worked bt having probplem with line 19, look at the extract   

   if($result){
    $_SESSION['loged'] = "$loFmUname";
    header('location:index.html');
    die();
   }

Comment: Replace the if conditions as follows if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0) and Try it

Answer (score 0):

You need to use dot separators when doing manipulation to a variable inside a variable.

Also, should `$_SESSION['loged'] = '$loFmUname';` be that, or `$_SESSION['logged'] = '$loFmUname';`?

```
<?php
session_start();
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con){
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_exist = mysql_select_db("seta", $con);

$myUName = $_POST["username"];
$myPwd = $_POST["pwd"];
$loFmUname = strtolower($myUName);

if($db_exist){
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE $loFmUname='" . strtolower($db_field['UserName']) . "' AND $myPwd='$db_field['UserPwd']' ");

    if($result){
        $_SESSION['loged'] = '$loFmUname';
        header('Location: index.html');
        die();
    } else {
        echo "Invalid username and/or password please";
        echo "<a href='login.php'>try again</a>";
    }
} else {
    echo "Sorry Database Not Found";
}

mysql_close($con);
?>
```